# instaling node on CentOS

Tags: node.js, npm, centos6

I am trying to install node on `

```
CentOS 2.6.31.11-an_centos6-v42 #3 SMP Thu Oct 31 12:17:24 PDT 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I download the tar file from nodejs.org.

```
tar -xf node-v0.10.23.tar.gz
cd node-v0.10.23
./configure
make
```

I see node in node-v0.10.23/node pointing to out/Release/node. So node runs and all is well. npm is not working though. Not sure why.

I only see npm below node-v0.10.23, only in

```
./deps/npm
./deps/npm/bin/npm
./tools/msvs/npm
./doc/blog/npm
```

so npm is not working so no npm install. Am I missing a step?

Comment: After building, did you do a `make install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have special requirements, it’s easier to use the pre-compiled Linux binaries found on [the Node download page](http://nodejs.org/download/).

Alternatively, EPEL contains Node.js 0.10.22. There is a lag from release to when EPEL has the latest Node.js, but it isn’t too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Review the instruction in the *README.md* file of your nodejs directory, which states the full three steps:

```
Unix/MacIntosh:

./configure
make
make install
```

where **./configure** sets the configuration parameters that Makefile will use, **make** compiles the code and generates the binaries executables and **make install** moves these binaries executables to  the correct directories. Moving these binaries executables to the correct directories is a non-negotiable requirement for you to actually be able to run **node** and **npm**

As a general piece of advice, make a habit of going through the README files before you compiie anything - you'll thank me the first time ou avoid a nasty surprise :)

Answer (score 0):

Additional simple way to install nodejs on CentOS, is to use a [repository](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions).

```
#first update the server packages:
    sudo yum -y update
#download and run the setup package script
    #as root
    curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
#Then install nodejs using yum
    yum install -y nodejs
#For npm Install Development Tools
    yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
#Last step install Forever to run your scripts
    sudo npm install forever -g
```

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.